# How can I upgrade ASP.NET external Facebook login to use a different API version?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, graph, owin

I recently got this email from Facebook, and I don't know how to update the ASP.NET code to call a different API version.

"... has been making recent API calls to Graph API v2.0, which will reach the end of the 2-year deprecation window on Monday, August 8, 2016. Please migrate all calls to v2.1 or higher in order to avoid potential broken experiences.

We recommend using our new Graph API Upgrade Tool to see which of your calls are affected by this change as well as any replacement calls in newer versions. You can also use our changelog to see the full list of changes."

The current code is:

```
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
            appId: "...",
            appSecret: "...");
```

Comment: I also got this email and I'm not sure about how to do this either.  One thing I've done is to ensure that the nuget package is up to date, but it already is.

Comment: I did it too before investigating it, all owin packages were up to date. Anyway since they still use version 2.0 it means that  the endpoint never got updated in all of the owin versions.

Answer (score 2):

I changed the code to something like that:

```
 app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AppId = "...",
            AppSecret = "...",
            AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://www.facebook.com/v2.6/dialog/oauth",
            UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me"
        });
```

If you use also Facebook SDK in Javascript, you can also change the FB.init to this:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: '...',
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.6'
    });
};
```

Comment: I don't suppose if you know that this is _the_ way to do it?  I expected that this might be something that was addressed by Microsoft by way of an update to the `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook` Nuget package.  The default value for `AuthorizationEndpoint` is https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth This doesn't even specify an API version...

Comment: It doesn't specify the version because it probably uses the first version. I got to this solution by reading Facebook references and reading how to customize the endpoints of the UseFacebookAuthentication.
It's not that I read somewhere about this specific solution.

Comment: Yes, that is the way to do it. This has been updated in the next version https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook/FacebookDefaults.cs